# iOS app rejected due to AppTrackingTransparency framework used in another target

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, apptrackingtransparency

I have several targets in my project using the same codebase, but only some of them are supposed to use AppTrackingTransparency framework.

I imported it using a compiler directive:

```
#if TRANSPARENCY
import AppTrackingTransparency
#endif
```

Where `TRANSPARENCY` is added in **Swift Compiler - Custom Flags/Other Swift Flags** as `-DTRANSPARENCY` only for targets where it's needed.

The same directive is wrapping a piece of code that actually presents the permission dialog.

However one of the targets that does NOT import AppTrackingTransparency was rejected with a request:

> Your app uses the AppTrackingTransparency framework, but we are unable
> to locate the App Tracking Transparency permission request. Please
> explain where we can find the App Tracking Transparency permission
> request in your app.

Did I miss something and AppTrackingTransparency is still being added in all targets? Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: You're still linking it. The imports doesn't change that

Comment: @ClausJørgensen then what does actually make it to be linked? I didn't do anything else besides importing in order to use it.

Comment: Have you tried responding and explaining that this particular app doesn't use ATT, but it is linked in due to a shared module?

Comment: @Paulw11 trying that right now, but regardless, I'm curious to know - how come that the framework is still linked to the app despite of being excluded by the compiler directive.